# Alternative for Positive Lookahead on Big Query - Match everything before the last delimiter

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm currently cleaning up URLs and I want to get everything before the last slash ("/")

This is an example string:
https://www.businessinsider.de/gruenderszene/plus-angebot/?tpcc=onsite_gs_header_nav&verification_code=DOVCGF75J8LSID

and the part I want to extract is: https://www.businessinsider.de/gruenderszene/plus-angebot

With normal RegEx, it is super simple with `.*(?=\/)`

You can see it here on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RdXOet/1)

Can you help me to replicate this on BigQuery please, as they don't allow for lookahead/lookbehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might phrase this as a regex replacement which removes the last path separator and path:

```sql
SELECT url, REGEXP_REPLACE(url, r'/[^/]+$', '') AS url_out
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to specifically target a final path separator immediately followed by a query parameter, then use:

```sql
SELECT url, REGEXP_REPLACE(url, r'/\?[^/]+$', '') AS url_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Definitely works for my case. But I have not quite understood the difference between both. Can you further clarify for me?

Comment: The second version insists that a `?` follow the final `/` path separator.  This is the only difference.